# Android AppCompat - equivalent of RingtonePreference?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I get an exception when I try to retain RingtonePreference in UserPreference screen after upgrading it to AppCompatActivity, but could not find an equivalent one. Please let me know if there are any links available that might help me, appreciate your help.

### Update

I also upgraded to PreferenceSupportFragment, that was when I got this error.

Comment: What exactly was the exception?

Comment: That class exists, so you must be doing something else wrong. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/RingtonePreference.html

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I upgraded to PreferenceSupportFragment

Comment: Sorry, haven't used that preference class, so not sure. It would help if you mentioned the exact exception message + some code you're converting, though

Comment: The only reason I was trying to upgrade to PreferenceSupportFragment was that the Toolbar does not show in the inner screen of user preferences. It shows only in the 1st level screen. If you can help me fix that, it will be great.